# How to force user to click button step in bootstraptour?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

> i will make guide for my aplication user in first time using bootstraptour, and i want to make user can't click other button except the button in step. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you can use the event method `preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
$(".disable-buttons button:not(.next-button)").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="disable-buttons">
<a href="www.google.com"><button class="btn btn-primary">1</button></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><button class="btn btn-primary">2</button></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><button class="btn btn-primary">3</button></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><button class="btn btn-primary">4</button></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><button class="btn btn-primary">5</button></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><button class="btn btn-primary">6</button></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><button class="btn btn-primary next-button">7</button></a>
</div>
```